# Master page and performance

Tags: asp.net

Can master pages increase performance of the application in case of loading time or it is just to reuse the design and making consistency. Or has it overhead(taking time) while events execution for both the content page and master page.

Comment: The overhead on a typical master page is minimal, but it depends what you choose to put on the master page.  Code that is set to run on Page_Load will run for every page, so if you put a lot of stuff in your master page it will take time to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for the reuse of the design and making consistency.

The full page with the master page and the other controls, and all the dependencies, makes a minimal overhead which is so small, maybe 1-2 millisecond, therefore there is no reason to talk about it.

I check now my biggest page, have 87 dependencies* , and it takes 70ms to start showing, all of them are database cost, and not because of the dependencies.

[*] one master, one page, and the rest custom controls, I see the compiled version on the temporary folder and there is a line that shows that.