# Is it a good idea to use plain HTML instead of ASPX

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm developing an ASP.NET website. Sometimes some modules contain so few content that I present them inside a jQUeryUI dialog and communicate with the server via AJAX. I keep those contents inside a separate file and load them to a jQueryUI dialog according to the appropriate module.I was wondering if it's a good idea to have that content as a plain HTML elements instead of asp ones. Somehow I thought maybe this would reduce the overhead the conversion from asp elements to html elements can cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is probably premature optimization. The overhead of an aspx page is in almost all cases negligible. I believe it's more likely that you will some day need to put dynamic things in that page, in which case you would have to convert the html file to an aspx, and change the url for your ajax dialog - which will cost time/money.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic things"? Can you give me an example of what I can do with aspx that I can not in html.

Comment: Show/hide fields depending on if the user is an administrator or not for example. That is, anything that only the server knows about, such as your session. There are ways around that too... But generally aspx is a lot better than static html for anything that is dependent on some server state.

Comment: But that needs a postback isn't it? So this dynamicity brings an obligation to postback.

Comment: Nope, when you fetch the page the page is rendered server side. So you don't need a postback to show/hide things, it's already done on server side before the page reaches the client.

Comment: This is true only when you do dynamic things on page load. What if you  want to show something that's currently not visible based on an operation you perform after the page is loaded.

Comment: Then you either use javascript or do a postback.
But what I'm saying is that perhaps you only want to perform that operation if a certain condition is true - a condition that perhaps only the server knows something about. The easiest way for the server to convey this message to the client is to modify the dom. The server could set a javascript variable for example, which would make the javascript code on the client perform different actions. So again, aspx is useful for something only the server would know about, such as user permissions, last modified dates, anything from database etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'd allways go with the aspx Page, because a dynamic Page is more work at the beginning but in the end it almost ever saves time.
Specially when your not sure of the content that will be shown there, it is better.
And for the one reason i do it, is to have everything the same.
One style one way to code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have aspx pages, or ascs user controls that you do not actually use/run any code, you can set the `AutoEventWireup` the `EnableViewState`, and maybe the `EnableSessionState` to **false** and stop the calling of the PageLoad and the rest functions and reduce the overhead. So on top of the controls you declare:

```
<%@ Control AutoEventWireup="false" EnableViewState="false" ...
```

or for page:

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="false" EnableViewState="false" EnableSessionState="false" ...
```

The disable of the session is let the pages loads in parallel, the disable of the EnableViewState is reduce the size, the AutoEventWireup is reduce the callback hooks and calls.

In general you can use what ever you wish - if your pages can work, but if you like to keep it robust and easy to change or update, or add new functionality in the future, then use dynamic aspx pages.

Similar question: [Master page and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256441/master-page-and-performance)